# C++ error: no matching function for call to 'Track::Track(char, char)'

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I'm trying to assign a one-dimensional array to my default constructor, but I keep getting this error message. Is there a way to create two default constructors for the same class, one with no parameters and one with parameters?

**header**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std; 

#ifndef SUBWAY_H
#define SUBWAY_H


class Track
{
    public:
    //Default Constructor 
    Track();                      //error here 

    //Destructor 
    ~Track();

    //Member variables 
    char node_1; 
    char node_2; 
    bool visited; 
};


class Station
{
    public:
    //Default Constructor 
    Station();

    //Destructor 
    ~Station();

    //Member variables 
    char station_name; 
    int track_starting_ID;
    int track_size; 
};


class SubwaySystem
{
    public:
    //Default Constructor
    SubwaySystem();

    //Destructor 
    ~SubwaySystem();

    //Member variables 
    Track my_track[34];
    Station my_station[12];

    int count_routes; 
};



#endif
```

**cpp**

```
#include "subway.h"

SubwaySystem::SubwaySystem()
{
    my_track[0] = Track('a', 'b'); //error here 
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any constructor for class Track which accepts two parameters. Due to this you are getting a compiler error. You need to define a 2 parameter constructor for class Track.

Comment: So I added Track(char a, char b) but now I'm getting undefined references on my cpp file.

Comment: Did you define the two parameter constructor in your cpp file?

Comment: I believe so. I have: Track::Track(char a, char b)
{
 node_1 = a;
 node_2 = b;
}

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I didn't define the destructors in the cpp file.